# Pickling, then Unpickling a scikit-learn model doesn't yield the original model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

This code throws an `AssertionError`:

```
model = RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(np.array([np.array([1]), np.array([2]), np.array([3])]), np.array([1, 2, 3]))
pk = pickle.dumps(model)
model2 = pickle.loads(pk)
assert model == model2
```

Is this expected? Is there a better way way to serialize an sklearn model?

Comment: Equality of models probably isn't implemented in a clever way, so python just reports that the objects aren't the same object in memory. A more practical comparison would be between fitted attributes or predictions on some data.

Comment: @BenReiniger this is what I thought initially as well, but when I compare the pickled values, they are indeed different bytes. Not sure if this is a bug.